# git status difference between git clients

Tags: git, cocoapods, atlassian-sourcetree, github-for-mac, github-desktop

For the last few years I'm using [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com) as git client. Yesterday I tried last version of [Github Desktop](https://desktop.github.com) (version Infinite Lop (214)). It’s better than all other version that I tried before. Still not better than SourceTree, but anyway I like it :) And I decide to use instead of SourceTree for a while.

But today I open another project and I was surprise with some file statuses. It’s shows that there are over 90 uncommitted changes :

[image]

But in fact I only change few files. How it’s happen. For to be sure, I check in terminal for same project with :

```
=> git status
```

but surprise surprise, it shows same results on OSX's git version too :

```
On branch SomeBranchNameOfProject
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   Podfile
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperation.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFHTTPSessionManager.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFNetworkReachabilityManager.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFSecurityPolicy.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFURLResponseSerialization.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/UIActivityIndicatorView+AFNetworking.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/UIAlertView+AFNetworking.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/UIButton+AFNetworking.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/UIProgressView+AFNetworking.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/UIRefreshControl+AFNetworking.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/UIWebView+AFNetworking.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/BPXLUUIDHandler/BPXLUUIDHandler.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/CocoaLumberjack/DDASLLogCapture.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/CocoaLumberjack/DDASLLogger.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/CocoaLumberjack/DDAbstractDatabaseLogger.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/CocoaLumberjack/DDAssertMacros.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/CocoaLumberjack/DDContextFilterLogFormatter.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/CocoaLumberjack/DDDispatchQueueLogFormatter.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/CocoaLumberjack/DDFileLogger.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/CocoaLumberjack/DDLegacyMacros.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/CocoaLumberjack/DDLog+LOGV.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/CocoaLumberjack/DDLog.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/CocoaLumberjack/DDLogMacros.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/CocoaLumberjack/DDMultiFormatter.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/CocoaLumberjack/DDTTYLogger.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/MBProgressHUD/MBProgressHUD.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/MMDrawerController/MMDrawerBarButtonItem.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/MMDrawerController/MMDrawerController+Subclass.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/MMDrawerController/MMDrawerController.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/MMDrawerController/MMDrawerVisualState.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/MMDrawerController/UIViewController+MMDrawerController.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/Mantle/MTLJSONAdapter.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/Mantle/MTLModel+NSCoding.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/Mantle/MTLModel.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/Mantle/MTLReflection.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/Mantle/MTLTransformerErrorHandling.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/Mantle/MTLValueTransformer.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/Mantle/Mantle.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/Mantle/NSArray+MTLManipulationAdditions.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/Mantle/NSDictionary+MTLJSONKeyPath.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/Mantle/NSDictionary+MTLManipulationAdditions.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/Mantle/NSDictionary+MTLMappingAdditions.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/Mantle/NSError+MTLModelException.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/Mantle/NSObject+MTLComparisonAdditions.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/Mantle/NSValueTransformer+MTLInversionAdditions.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/Mantle/NSValueTransformer+MTLPredefinedTransformerAdditions.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/Reachability/Reachability.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/SDWebImage/NSData+ImageContentType.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/SDWebImage/SDImageCache.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/SDWebImage/SDWebImageCompat.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/SDWebImage/SDWebImageDecoder.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/SDWebImage/SDWebImageDownloader.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/SDWebImage/SDWebImageDownloaderOperation.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/SDWebImage/SDWebImageManager.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/SDWebImage/SDWebImageOperation.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/SDWebImage/SDWebImagePrefetcher.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/SDWebImage/UIButton+WebCache.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/SDWebImage/UIImage+GIF.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/SDWebImage/UIImage+MultiFormat.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/SDWebImage/UIImageView+HighlightedWebCache.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h
    typechange: Pods/Headers/Public/SDWebImage/UIView+WebCacheOperation.h
```

in fact SourceTree doesn’t show that files with “Changes not staged for commit” warning!

I know that source tree uses own embeded Git, and I could change that in preferences :

[image]

That means, SourceTree could show same "not staged files" too probably...

My question is, how could I use Github Desktop with same experience like how I use SourceTree? And what is wrong with my CocoaPods files. Or if I understand something wrong, please guide me to fix this behaviour.

Comment: "typechange" means that the file changed *types*, most likely from symbolic link to regular file (or vice versa).  Usually this happens because the files were originally symbolic links (and checked in to git that way at some point) and then some program that does not handle symlinks replaced each file with its target (so that now git tells you that the type has changed).  Exactly what changed them, and why, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking my question I update my `OSX` to `version 10.11.1 (15B42)` and `XCode` to `Version 7.1 (7B91b)`. But things get worse XCode start to show **question mark for all files in workspace** (means : *file untracked by source control*). That moment I realise something wrong with my **.git directory** in my workspace. I open the terminal and enter inside of .git directory. And I check old copy of my project from my backup directory (If you have a backup you are lucky...). It was different than before. I know that SourceTree was adding `sourcetreeconfig` directory in my .git directory and there was more than this. I understand that *Github Desktop* add that directories and everybody (all clients) effect each other except lovely sweet sweet SourceTree! I want to say thank you for team and [Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com).

Solution : I remove other directories created from Github Desktop and everything working like a charm now.

So my adverture with Github Desktop paused by now. But after few days I’ll try again but only work with Github Desktop this time. Why? Because I love it :)

Thank you for your comment @torek.